# UITableView Inserting Rows Invalid Update

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have worked with deleting and reloading rows at specified index paths but never inserting. Here is what I am trying to do:

```
func reloadTableView(newIndexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
    print(dataSource.numberOfItems()) // prints 44
    print(newIndexPaths.count) // prints 22
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: newIndexPaths, with: .none)
    tableView.endUpdates() // Crashes before this line
}
```

And here is the crash that I receive:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 2.  The number of rows contained in an
>   existing section after the update (44) must be equal to the number of
>   rows contained in that section before the update (22), plus or minus
>   the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted,
>   0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of
>   that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

What doesn't make sense is that it tells me that only 1 item was trying to be inserted but in fact I am actually inserting 22. My data source is properly updated so why isn't this working?

Comment: Check the contents of `newIndexPaths` - are there 22 distinct indexpaths in there, or one indexpath 22 times?

Answer (score 0):

@Paulw11 Yep! That was exactly the issue and I can't believe I didn't catch that. When I was creating my indexPaths, I prematurely forgot to increment the row value as I was looping through my creation process. Thanks!